# Jquery Mobile CDN alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm tryna use Jquery MObile. So instead of using CDN, I've used the folloging code in my html page

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

It does not seems to work. Jquery, Jquery Mobile or even the css file are not rendred in my web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>FIRST PAGE</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
        <p>Welcome </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>&copy; Test</h2>   
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Do you guyyz know why it's not working ?  (from what I've understood so far there should be some styling on the header and the footer. But this is not working here

PS: I've tried with CDN and it works with CDN BUT I dont want to use CDN as I'm coding for a local application only

**ScreenShot ofmy JqueryFolder**
[image]

**Console Error ScreenShot**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be because you are using forward slashes "\" instead of backslashes "/".

From our comment discussion we can also see that the scripts are loading in the wrong order.

Jquery Mobile needs Jquery (main) to run and so the latter (Jquery) needs to be loaded **first**.

So...

This:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JqueryFiles\jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

should be this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JqueryFiles/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="JqueryFiles/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="JqueryFiles/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Nope still not working. I tried \ as / would work just to see if it'd make a difference. Still both slashes produce the same result. SO I'm on windows.  The index.html is right outside the folder. I added a picture of my JqueryFiles folder in my OP. Seriously I have no idea what's going. It should be straightforward.

Comment: `ctrl + shit + j` brouth me an error console error (with or without the forward slash I get the same error) in google chrome. Please see my OP for the screenshot of the error